# Making use of awk on strings

Tags: awk

I'm interested in listing in the terminal the lines from a csv file where the first character is 'A' . Is there a prompt way to do that?

Comment: Crossposted on Ask Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/560569/making-use-of-awk-on-string

Comment: In case you weren't aware, [cross-posting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-que) on Stack Exchange sites is frowned upon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose you have the file:

```
~$ cat f
1,AA,2
2,BB,2
3, AA, 1
C, BA, 1
```

You can simply use grep:

```
~$ grep "^[^,], *A" f
1,AA,2
3, AA, 1
```

But it is possible with awk with the same regexp:

```
~$ awk '/^[^,], *A/' f
1,AA,2
3, AA, 1
```

and a better way is to use the field separator (`-F','`) and test the second field:

```
~$  awk -F',' '$2~/^ *A/' f
1,AA,2
3, AA, 1
```

And with sed:

```
~$ sed -n '/^[^,], *A/p' f
1,AA,2
3, AA, 1
```

---

Note that these commands won't work if you have a comma inside a quoted field like:

```
"1,A",AA,A
'1,A',AA,A
```

If that's the case, you will have to use programs like [csvquote](https://github.com/dbro/csvquote), [ocaml-csv](https://github.com/Chris00/ocaml-csv), or your own…

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the string in which we look for the 'A' character is on the second column.

Comment: What happens if the first column is a quoted string that contains a comma? Such as `"This is the 1st column, and it's rather long", AA, 2`. Simple `awk` and `grep` searches will fail here. It might not be relevant for @user43389 's data, but it's worth keeping in mind.

Comment: Indeed, it's worth noting